# How to export to excel with custom style in react js

Tags: reactjs

I want to export  to excel with custom styles headers and font styles in excel in reactjs

I have tried all . But i could not get it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I want to implement above code in typescript with custom styles to excel sheet ( adding color to first row in cell ).

Answer (score 1):

u can use the npm package react-data-export

[reat-data-export](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-data-export)

[example of usage with custom style](https://github.com/securedeveloper/react-data-export/blob/HEAD/examples/styled_excel_sheet.md)